# persistence jsonb field to h2 using hibernate

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, h2, jsonb

[source code](https://github.com/sakitA/h2jsonb)

I want to use `jsonb` column type. When I used `postgresql` there is no problem. But when I use `H2` I can not persist my entity. Native sql works but when saving `EntityManager.persist`  i got below error

```
ERROR: Data conversion error converting "X'aced000574000f7b226b6579223a2276616c7565227d' (json_entities: ""attributes"" ""JSONB"")"; SQL statement:
insert into json_entities (attributes, id) values (?, ?) [22018-200]
javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convertCommitException(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:104)
    at H2Test.jsonFieldTest(H2Test.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.evaluate(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:100)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:103)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:220)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:53)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:154)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:181)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convertCommitException(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:65)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:52)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:200)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3254)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3779)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:107)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:604)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.lambda$executeActions$1(ActionQueue.java:478)
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:684)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:475)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:348)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:40)
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:102)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1360)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:451)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3210)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2378)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:447)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:183)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$300(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:40)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:281)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:101)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLDataException: Data conversion error converting "X'aced000574000f7b226b6579223a2276616c7565227d' (json_entities: ""attributes"" ""JSONB"")"; SQL statement:
insert into json_entities (attributes, id) values (?, ?) [22018-200]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:457)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:429)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:194)
    at org.h2.table.Column.getDataConversionError(Column.java:409)
    at org.h2.table.Column.validateConvertUpdateSequence(Column.java:381)
    at org.h2.table.Table.validateConvertUpdateSequence(Table.java:845)
    at org.h2.command.dml.Insert.insertRows(Insert.java:187)
    at org.h2.command.dml.Insert.update(Insert.java:151)
    at org.h2.command.CommandContainer.update(CommandContainer.java:198)
    at org.h2.command.Command.executeUpdate(Command.java:251)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:191)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:152)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:197)
    ... 47 more
Caused by: org.h2.message.DbException: Data conversion error converting "OTHER to JSON" [22018-200]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:205)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:181)
    at org.h2.value.Value.getDataConversionError(Value.java:1504)
    at org.h2.value.Value.convertToJson(Value.java:1439)
    at org.h2.value.Value.convertTo(Value.java:861)
    at org.h2.value.Value.convertTo(Value.java:772)
    at org.h2.value.TypeInfo.cast(TypeInfo.java:515)
    at org.h2.table.Column.validateConvertUpdateSequence(Column.java:378)
    ... 57 more
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLDataException: Data conversion error converting "OTHER to JSON" [22018-200]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:457)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:429)
    ... 65 more
```

Here is my simple project.

**Custom hibernate type for jsonb**

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.engine.spi.SharedSessionContractImplementor;
import org.hibernate.usertype.UserType;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Types;

/**
 * Created by sanco on 29/09/2020.
 * h2jsontest
 */
public class PGJsonType implements UserType {
    private final int CUSTOM_TYPE = Types.OTHER;
    private final static ObjectMapper jsonMapper = new ObjectMapper();


    @Override
    public int[] sqlTypes() {
        return new int[]{CUSTOM_TYPE};
    }

    @Override
    public Class returnedClass() {
        return JsonNode.class;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object x, Object y) throws HibernateException {
        return x==null? y==null : ((JsonNode)x).equals((JsonNode)y);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode(Object x) throws HibernateException {
        return ((JsonNode)x).hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public Object nullSafeGet(ResultSet rs, String[] names, SharedSessionContractImplementor session, Object owner) throws HibernateException, SQLException {
        final String cellContent = rs.getString(names[0]);
        if (cellContent == null) {
            return null;
        }
        try {
            return jsonMapper.readTree(cellContent);
        } catch (final Exception ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to convert jsonb to JsonNode: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void nullSafeSet(PreparedStatement st, Object value, int index, SharedSessionContractImplementor session) throws HibernateException, SQLException {
        if (value == null) {
            st.setNull(index, CUSTOM_TYPE);
            return;
        }
        try {
            st.setObject(index, jsonMapper.writeValueAsString(value), CUSTOM_TYPE);
        } catch (final Exception ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to convert JsonNode to jsonb: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object deepCopy(Object value) throws HibernateException {
        return value==null? null : ((JsonNode)value).deepCopy();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isMutable() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Serializable disassemble(Object value) throws HibernateException {
        return (Serializable) value;
    }

    @Override
    public Object assemble(Serializable cached, Object owner) throws HibernateException {
        return cached;
    }

    @Override
    public Object replace(Object original, Object target, Object owner) throws HibernateException {
        return original;
    }
}
```

**my entity class**

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Type;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

/**
 * Created by sanco on 29/09/2020.
 * h2jsontest
 */
@Entity
@Table(name="json_entities")
public class JsonEntity {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Type(type = "PGJsonType")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "jsonb")
    private JsonNode attributes;

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public JsonNode getAttributes() {
        return attributes;
    }

    public void setAttributes(JsonNode attributes) {
        this.attributes = attributes;
    }
}
```

**persistence unit**

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
             version="2.0">

    <persistence-unit name="postgre">
        <description>
            Hibernate using JPA
        </description>

        <class>JsonEntity</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="postgres"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="s2351910"/>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL10Dialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults"
                      value="false"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/>
            <property name="hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class"
                      value="org.hibernate.hikaricp.internal.HikariCPConnectionProvider"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hikari.minimumIdle" value="5"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hikari.maximumPoolSize" value="20"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hikari.idleTimeout" value="45000"/>

        </properties>

    </persistence-unit>

    <persistence-unit name="h2">
        <description>
            Hibernate using JPA
        </description>

        <class>JsonEntity</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:h2:mem:organization;MODE=PostgreSQL;IGNORECASE=TRUE;DATABASE_TO_LOWER=TRUE;AUTO_RECONNECT=TRUE;INIT=CREATE DOMAIN IF NOT EXISTS jsonb AS other\;CREATE TYPE if not exists &quot;JSONB&quot; AS json;"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.h2.Driver"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="sa"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value=""/>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults"
                      value="false"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/>
            <property name="hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class"
                      value="org.hibernate.hikaricp.internal.HikariCPConnectionProvider"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hikari.minimumIdle" value="5"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hikari.maximumPoolSize" value="20"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hikari.idleTimeout" value="60000"/>

        </properties>

    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

**test classes**
**H2**

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode;
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

/**
 * Created by sanco on 29/09/2020.
 * h2jsontest
 */
public class H2Test {
    private static EntityManagerFactory factory;
    private static ObjectMapper mapper;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void init(){
        factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("h2");
        mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    }

    @Test
    public void jsonFieldTest(){
        EntityManager em = factory.createEntityManager();

        JsonEntity je = new JsonEntity();
        je.setId(1L);

        ObjectNode on = mapper.createObjectNode();
        on.put("key", "value");
        je.setAttributes(on);

        try {
            em.getTransaction().begin();
            em.persist(je);
            em.getTransaction().commit();

            
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            em.getTransaction().rollback();
        }
```

assert (em.createQuery("select j.id from JsonEntity j", Long.class).getSingleResult())==1L;
}

```
    @AfterClass
    public static void cleanResource(){
        if(factory!=null)
            factory.close();
    }
}
```

**Postgresql**

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode;
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

/**
 * Created by sanco on 29/09/2020.
 * h2jsontest
 */
public class PostgreSQLTest {
    private static EntityManagerFactory factory;
    private static ObjectMapper mapper;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void init(){
        factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("postgre");
        mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    }

    @Test
    public void jsonFieldTest(){
        EntityManager em = factory.createEntityManager();

        JsonEntity je = new JsonEntity();
        je.setId(1L);

        ObjectNode on = mapper.createObjectNode();
        on.put("key", "value");
        je.setAttributes(on);

        try {
            em.getTransaction().begin();
            em.persist(je);
            em.getTransaction().commit();

            
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            em.getTransaction().rollback();
        }
```

assert (em.createQuery("select j.id from JsonEntity j", Long.class).getSingleResult())==1L;
}

```
    @AfterClass
    public static void cleanResource(){
        if(factory!=null)
            factory.close();
    }
}
```

I read lots of forms but the suggested solution does not work for me. I also debug the `H2` source code and see that `ValueJson.convertToJson` throw exception because of value type not handle on switch case. Look at the source code of [org.h2.value.Value.java](https://github.com/h2database/h2database/blob/e1bcf3b6ba8927ff640299c879011f2df0750ef9/h2/src/main/org/h2/value/Value.java#L1412)

```
private ValueJson convertToJson() {
        switch (getValueType()) {
        case BOOLEAN:
            return ValueJson.get(getBoolean());
        case BYTE:
        case SHORT:
        case INT:
            return ValueJson.get(getInt());
        case LONG:
            return ValueJson.get(getLong());
        case FLOAT:
        case DOUBLE:
        case DECIMAL:
            return ValueJson.get(getBigDecimal());
        case BYTES:
        case BLOB:
            return ValueJson.fromJson(getBytesNoCopy());
        case STRING:
        case STRING_IGNORECASE:
        case STRING_FIXED:
        case CLOB:
            return ValueJson.get(getString());
        case GEOMETRY: {
            ValueGeometry vg = (ValueGeometry) this;
            return ValueJson.getInternal(GeoJsonUtils.ewkbToGeoJson(vg.getBytesNoCopy(), vg.getDimensionSystem()));
        }
        default:
            throw getDataConversionError(Value.JSON);
        }
    }
```

`getValueType` return `19` which means `JAVA_OBJECT`. How can I handle this problem?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @SimonH no without changing source code you can not use hibernate. So that I used native sql when persist the data

Comment: Thanks for replying. I started to use testcontainers and run a postgres container when executing my junit/integration tests

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Spring Boot with Liquibase and this library (https://github.com/vladmihalcea/hibernate-types) to accomplish this.  And this article to accomplish this https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-map-json-objects-using-generic-hibernate-types/.

The first step is have a Liquibase change set that only runs in test mode to treat JSONB column types as JSON. H2 supports the latter but not the former.

This is the first change set that runs, and it is only targeted if the context is test and if the target DB is H2.

```xml
<changeSet id="0" author="psc" context="test" dbms="h2">
  <sql>
    CREATE TYPE IF NOT EXISTS "JSONB" as json;
  </sql>
</changeSet>
```

Contents of `application-test.properties`

```
spring.liquibase.contexts=test
```

My test entity. See `How to map json` article to better understand the annotations that were used.

```java
import com.vladmihalcea.hibernate.type.json.JsonType;
import lombok.*;
import net.energyhub.testcontainers.dto.CustomerData;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Type;
import org.hibernate.annotations.TypeDef;
import org.hibernate.annotations.TypeDefs;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "customers")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@TypeDefs({
        @TypeDef(name = "json", typeClass = JsonType.class)
})
public class Customer {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    @Type(type = "json")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "jsonb")
    private CustomerData customerDetails;
}
```

Example of a test that exercises the JSON column. I'm making use of Spring Boot's DataJPATest test slice feature.

```java
@DataJpaTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class CustomerServiceH2Test {
    @Autowired
    private CustomerRepository customerRepository;

    @Test
    public void testFindAll() {
        Customer customer = Customer.builder()
                .name("Phil Calouche")
                .customerDetails(CustomerData.builder().x("x-value").build())
                .build();
        customerRepository.save(customer);

        assertThat(customerRepository.findAll()).hasSize(4);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for sharing. currently I use native sql instead of using hibernate. maybe next version they can do something about that

Comment: @sancho you may be able to add to an init state in your H2 URL.  Here's a reference link http://h2database.com/html/features.html#execute_sql_on_connection.  So maybe a URL that looks something like this: 

jdbc:h2:mem:test;INIT=CREATE TYPE IF NOT EXISTS "JSONB" as json